# Android View: hide if layout_height too small

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I want to show just two TextViews on the screen, one on top of the other.

TextView B: 400dp high, at the bottom,
TextView A: fill the rest of the screen.

However, if the height of TextView A is less than 100dp, it shouldn't be displayed (only TextView A visible, the rest is just white space).

Can this be achieved just by XML?

Currently I'm using something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:text="Image A"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:text="Image B: 400dp"
        android:gravity="center"        
        android:textSize="40sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in code you can do if textviewb.getHeight < 100 then textviewb.setVisibility(View.Gone);

Comment: How can your view B be less than 100dp, if you want to set it to 400dp and fill the rest of the space with View A? A typo maybe? And you will have to do some check in the code to achieve this

Comment: I think you want `android:maxHeight="400dp"` instead of `android:layout_height="400dp"` becuase that will make your TExtView ALWAYS 400dp and so you will never have less than 100. Then fill the TextView programatically and then follow MarkoNiciforovic's suggestion.

Comment: The second TextView should have "layout_weight="0"", I think.

Comment: @Alex Orlov: Yes, it's a typo, sorry.
I mean "if the height of TextView A is less than 100dp, it shouldn't be displayed".

Answer (score 0):

If you were going to use this feature in several other layouts, I'd consider building it into a custom view, where you can add an extra attribute customer:minSize=100dp.  In that custom view, you could probably then add Marko's suggestion (i.e. textview.getHeight > customer:minSize then textview.setVisibility(View.Gone/Invisible)

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html
...
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-custom-views-2/

Otherwise, I'd just implement it in your activity.